# Django primary key does not exist

Tags: django

I have a script that I am using to populate an sqlite3 database from a .txt file in django however once the data is loaded in it I don't seem to be able to reference the objects with a pk. I can confirm the data has been loaded by doing `./manage.py shell` and importing the City model and doing  `City.objects.all()` shows that the models are loaded into the database but if I do `City.object.get(pk=1)` then it thinks that the City object does not exist.

I have had some issues with the database in the past so I recently did `./manage.py flush` followed by a reinput of the data with the script. This is when things started to be an issue. Any ideas?

Also I know that I don't strictly need the uniqueID value but I don't think this is causing an issue, it hasn't in the past.

script for loading the data:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mygame.settings")
from geogame.models import City

f = open("testing.txt", 'r').readlines()

i = 1

for line in f:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.split('\t')
    line[6] = 1
    line[7] = 100
    c = City(name=line[1], uniqueID=i, xcoord=int(line[3]), ycoord=int(line[2]), country=line[4], population=line[5], times_played=line[6], average_distance=line[7], difficulty_rating=line[8])
    c.save()
    i+=1
```

the `models.py` file

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    uniqueID = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ycoord = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    xcoord = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    population = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    times_played = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    average_distance = models.FloatField(default=0)
    difficulty_rating = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the error message:

```
>>> City.objects.get(pk=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: City matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: My guess is that the record with `pk = 1` has been deleted.

Comment: But I would have thought that with the flush all the pk's would become available again?

Comment: try adding `id=i` in `c = City()`. So that every time you create a new one, the id is adding 1 to it.

Comment: That seems to have worked thanks @qasimalbaqali. From the documentation I have read it doesn't say that you need to explicitly increment the id...

Comment: @SamuelBarnett Yeah, as soon as I read that the id is not there, I looked out how you created it. I see that you are manually creating everything, and since it's a script and it's not a Django `script` you have to create every field in the model manually :) Glad I could help, I made my comment as an answer below, so it would be accepted and this question gets closed, happy coding!

Comment: @SamuelBarnett truncating a table does not reset the sequence that generates IDs, you need to do that explicitly with an UPDATE command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `id=i` in `c = City()`. So that every time you create a new one, the id is adding 1 to it.

```
c = City(id=i, name=line[1], uniqueID=i,
         xcoord=int(line[3]), ycoord=int(line[2]),
         country=line[4],
         population=line[5], times_played=line[6], average_distance=line[7],
         difficulty_rating=line[8])
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` in Your model has type [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField). This type of firld automaticaly increment values when new row is added.

You can overwrite `id` when You create a new row

```
c = City(id=1, name='test', ...)
c.save()
City.objects.get(pk=1)
```

or read inserted `id` after save model

```
c = City(name='test', ...)
c.save()
lastId = c.pk
City.objects.get(pk=lastId)
```